# How to override abstract controller

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

Can someone tell me how to override "Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig" .
I'm unable to override this abstract class by using preference and plugins.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?